# Can I use any modern Bluetooth dongle with a modern headset on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, desktop, dongle

I have a [Logitech H600 wireless headset](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-headset-h600) but have lost the USB dongle. I see I could buy a replacement dongle from Logitech for a reasonable price but I consider their postage cost unreasonable for such a tiny item.

Given that the Logitech dongle is Bluetooth 2.1 and is pre-paired with the headset if I just go into a shop locally and buy a Bluetooth dongle—assuming I can fınd one—will I be able to use it on my Windows 8.1 desktop to pair with the headset? I see there is headset pairing utility software on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pair your headset with your cell phone, I have done so with mine.  Given that, I would assume that any dongle that supports the latest Bluetooth standard would work.  I suggest buying from a retailer that will give you your money back if it does not.

Comment: I don't actually want to pair it with the phone (which is Android by the way) but that might give me a clue as to how to pair it with the desktop. So is yours the same make and model of headset and if so how did you pair it to the phone? The dongle was so cheap I won't bother asking for money back.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that the Logitech dongle is Bluetooth 2.1 and is pre-paired with
>   the headset if I just go into a shop locally and buy a Bluetooth
>   dongle—assuming I can fınd one—will I be able to use it on my Windows
>   8.1 desktop to pair with the headset? I see there is headset pairing utility software on their website.

In general if it’s a Bluetooth device, you should be able to pair it with any Bluetooth dongle. As [explained in the support area of their website](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-headset-h600) related to the headset pairing utility explains:

> …follow the on-screen instructions to pair your headset with your new
>   USB dongle.

Comment: I bought a very cheap Bluetooth (v2.0 as that was the only version they had) USB dongle in a local store. In "control panel" "view devices and printers" I can now see "Generic Bluetooth Radio".  Using the standard Windows 8.1 Bluetooth screen I can pair the desktop with my phone but cannot see the headset. 

However when I run the Logitech pairing utility it has the "next" button greyed out on the first step, which is "Insert the USB wireless nano receiver". Maybe the pairing utility only recognizes Logitech devices. 
Anyone know why the Bluetooth screen cannot detect the headset?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *any* headset will necessarily do bluetooth, but the H600 does ... kind-of. The [Logitech forums](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Earphones-Headphones-Headsets/H600-usb-Reciver/td-p/982471/highlight/true) [suggest](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Earphones-Headphones-Headsets/H600-Pairing-not-working/m-p/1374777/highlight/true#M27763) if you've got Bluetooth 4.0 (not 2.1) then you can get it connected but NOT with microphone support. No idea why. Very annoying as I was thinking of getting an H600 but would rely on bluetooth. Forum posts also suggest it's quite dependent on driver versions so worth a try but you might end up wasting a lot of time on it...